# How can I convert 1 ½ to 1.5

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I have the problem that I can convert ½ to 0.5 but I don't know how to convert 1 ½ to 1.5 or 2 ½ to 2.5. [This is the link](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1140221220253617/Supersaftiger-Apfelkuchen.html). There is the row 1 ½ kg and I think it would help me if you could show me e.g. a more advanced replace() parameter or something. This is what I already have to convert to 0.5:

```
    raw_string = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ingredient.get_text(strip=True))
    raw_string = raw_string.replace(u'\u00BD', "0.5")
```

Comment: ½ is a string literal, not a numerical value. It's just a human-readable-way of representing numerals. You will there for have to parse them manually as machines don't really know what they are. `b'\xc2\xbd'` is also `½` in `UTF-8` land for instance, or `b'\xbd'` in `ISO-8859-1`. So this will become entirely up to your input data encoding, and will fail across platforms. If possible, use another input source with proper numbers. There's no library for this that I know of, perhaps you could make one? :)

Comment: Okay but how could I solve it because at the end I want to get 100+ tables but some of them will have some values like ½ or 1½.

Comment: Well, you'll simply have to replace all possible combinations of [fractions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C2%BD) with whatever the numerical value is. And then compensate for encoding issues if the source of the data decides to not use [unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) anymore and perhaps start using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). This is a pretty broad question mind you.

Comment: There is no best solution. For me, I will just clean all of those data before it go into our backend system. e.g. A hook like what you wrote.

Comment: I think there should be some Unicode (as in Unicode Consortium, see their localization database) annex to solve this. In Python we have `unicodedata.numeric()` but just to get (in this case 1 and 0.5). Parsing and mixing in general it is much more complex (you may compose fractions, and you may have number in other scripts). I do not think the actual answer is the definitive one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A posssible solution:

```
# this converts any integer followed by ½ 
raw_string = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s*'+u'\u00BD', r'\1.5', raw_string)
# this takes care of lone ½ 
raw_string = raw_string.replace(u'\u00BD', "0.5")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this convert `2 ½` into `1.5`?

Comment: @Torxed, did you try?

Comment: @trincot That's in addition, not instead of OP's code. I'll make it clear.

Comment: @trincot I was on the phone, so no, hence why I asked. And since the answer didn't really contain information and was a [code only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/down-vote-code-only-answers) I wanted to make sure the answer was valid and didn't contain flaws. Or that more information was given :) Seams to do the trick tho and more information has been added since asking.

Comment: @Torxed I think you refer to `r'\1.5'`. The `\1` is a reference to the captured group, so it replaces the found text with the text from the captured group (`(\d+)`) plus `'.5'`.

Comment: note to future readers: this won't catch things like "¹⁄₂" which might look similar (depending on your fonts) to "½" but is actually three characters (superscript 1, fraction slash, subscript 2) or e.g. "¹/₂" which uses a forward slash (known in unicode as a solidus).  unicode normalisation can help but won't catch the latter